# Phantomjs issue with opening a page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have the below small piece of code through which i am trying to test if I can succcesfully open a website with Phantomjs.

It works well  with most websites except that with www.roca.com it goes into a hang state with no output.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url ='http://www.roca.in'
page.open(url, function(status) {


page.includeJs('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js',function() {

console.log('*****************************************************')
console.log('Opened ' +url + 'with status:'+status)
phantom.exit();
});
});
```

What is special about this website that this behaviour occurs ? Thanks

Edit: I have also tried using --ssl-protocol=any and it didnt work

Comment: There was a problem with PhantomJS and sites in India before. There was no solution. Try updating to PhantomJS 2 if you haven't already. Can you check whether the `includeJs()` fails or the outer `page.open()`?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks. I am using PhantomJS 2.0.1-development downloaded yesterday, so that may not be the issue.